# How to set startup .ini by default in Progress Developer Studio?

Tags: eclipse, parameters, startup, progress-4gl, openedge

I have some files that need to use Font from (.ini).

I have also tried the solution as in http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P30492, but it doesn't work.

If I set .ini file for specific class : 
Run Configurations > Startup > ini file, it works and error (4499) on RUNTIME is gone. 
 
 However, new classes / files are still at risk to show "FONT error (4499)" if I forgot to set the startup parameters for each new file.

Is there any way to set startup by default for the project / all files?

Current Version : Progress Developer Studio 11.6 (32-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the -basekey ini -ininame your.ini file startup parameter to the project properties.

Right click the project in the "Project explorer", choose properties, navigate to Progress OpenEdge.

Add "-basekey ini -ininame your.ini" to the project startup parameters.

This is inherited to every new run configuration and should solve your problem.

When your .ini file is not named progress.ini, you should be able to leave out the -basekey ini parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Mike for your solution, it takes me some time to realize that existing file doesn't automatically add the **Updated** startup parameter as in Project properties.

Comment: Yes. That's true :-( If you haven't customized the existing run config's largely, you might just delete all of them.

Comment: Does the startup parameter generated automatically after _existing run config_ deleted?

Comment: After deleting the old run configs each new Run should create a new run confug that includes the ini file parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation Mike.